# Why does my CodeMirror's height doesn't change with the CSS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, codemirror

I'm using CodeMirror to display a JSON (the component is inside a simple div):

```
<codemirror v-model="codeToPrint" class="CodeMirror" :options="cmOptions"/>
```

And here are my options :

```
cmOptions: {
      mode: "application/json",
      lineNumbers: true,
      lineWrapping: true,
      viewportMargin: Infinity,
      readOnly: true,
      matchBrackets: true,
    },
```

The size doesn't change even If I try `height : 1500px;` or any number. I try to search in the documentation but I didn't find any solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it need to be a string instead? `’height : ‘1500px’;`

Comment: No sadly... I tried `height="500px"` too, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS class:

```
.CodeMirror {
  height: 1500px
}
```

see https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config

> CodeMirror:
> The outer element of the editor. This should be used for the editor width,
> height, borders and positioning.